# Find all holomorphic real functions - Open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> An exercise asks to find all holomorphic real functions.

Clearly, I know that we could use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to conclude. However, I think we could use the open mapping theorem. Does someone could explain why this is true?

Comment: What does the open mapping theorem say and what does that imply if we assume a given holomorphic function only takes real values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open mapping theorem asserts that a non-constant holomorphic function takes open sets to open sets. The real line is not open in $\mathbb C$ - so if a holomorphic function maps to the real line, it must be constant.

Comment: I think it should be trivial, but I don't understand well your last sentence. Could you develop a bit more?

Comment: @Pineuf a line is not an open set in the usual topology in the plane. So if the function mapping to the real line were to be holomorphic, it would violate the open mapping theorem unless it were constant.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I didn't understand well the question. In fact, A real function is $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ instead of $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, immm.

Comment: Wait, what? The open mapping theorem isn't true if the function is defined on the real numbers - it must be defined on C and take values in R.

Comment: scuse me, I did a blunder in my previous comment. Yes, you are right.