# Why do we need the Open Mapping Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

One way of stating the Open Mapping Theorem is that non-constant holomorphic functions map open sets to open sets. I am kind of confused why this is remarkable. Isn't this a characteristic property of continuous functions anyways?

Comment: *(Commenting instead of answering since I think this is a duplicate:)* Absolutely not! Continuity is the opposite direction: the *preimage* of an open set with respect to a continuous function is open. For instance, consider (in $\mathbb{R}$) the $\sin$ function: this is continuous, but we have $$\sin[(0,17)]=[-1,1]$$ (remember $f[A]=\{f(a):a\in A\}$) which is not open. The open mapping theorem is actually extremely powerful: in $\mathbb{R}$-land, most(?) of the continuous functions we're used to are not open (a function is open iff it sends open sets to open sets).

Comment: Or even just a constant function

Comment: @MPW I wanted to pick a function whose "complex version" satisfies the hypotheses for the open mapping theorem, though.

Comment: Constant functions actually have to be excluded in this statement of the Open Mapping Theorem anyway. So it's a good idea to show the plethora of non-constant continuous functions which are not open. Like $f(z) = \lvert z \rvert$.

Comment: Just among the related question the AI shows up for me here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3932438/96384 looks like a near-duplicate, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124846/96384 looks like a nice "explanation", and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1734141/96384 gives an easy application which shows how much this differs from plain old real calculus, let alone just any continuous functions.